# USB device registration - logging only at stop request

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service, windows-services

please find the [code](http://pastebin.com/SRVRdiHJ) for the service created to detect my USB device.

The problem in the above code is that the logfile is getting updated only after the service is stopped.

My intension is to update the log file once the device is detected.. But it happens only after the service is stopped. how to achieve what i intend to?

please guide me..

Comment: That code is pretty big. Can you post a smaller sample that still shows the behaviour? But you probably need to flush your file after you write to it. File IO in C is buffered, so writes do not go to the disk until you have written enough to fill the buffer, close the file or flush it (read about `fflush`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid losing log entries, you need to flush the `fwrite`s .

`fflush(your file handle )`